# In-center of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, determinant, analytic-geometry

In geometry the in-center is the point of intersection/concurrence of angle bisectors;

If I have a triangle with three vertices
$$A=(x_a,y_a), B=(x_b,y_b), C=(x_c,y_c),$$

known to be related by

$$\left( \frac{ax_a + bx_b + cx_c}{a+b+c};\frac{ay_a + by_b + cy_c}{a+b+c} \right) \tag 1$$

how can I find/derive the above formula $(1)$ using the determinant of a matrix or by any other means?

Comment: You should be more specific. The *incenter* is the point of intersection of the *angle* bisectors; the *circumcenter* is the point of intersection of the *perpendicular bisectors of the sides*.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hiiiiiii :-) I am scarce in English language. Please can you edit my question with your suggestion?

Comment: Well, honestly, what you've written confuses me. You refer to circumscribed polygons, but your discussion of areas seems to be referring to the inscribed circle and hence the incenter.

Comment: Do you just want a formula for coordinates of incenter, given three vertices using determinants?

Comment: I think most places you've written "circumscribed", you should actually say "inscribed". "Circumscribed polygons" is unclear - does it mean that the polygon is drawn around a circle (in which case of course it has an incircle)?

Comment: @aschepler I tried to eliminate what is superfluous or incorrect as a definition and not to create misunderstandings. I had copied from a textbook basically. If you could improve my question I am grateful further. Thank youuuuuuuuuuu.

Comment: @TedShifrin Kind Ted I edited my issue basically following your advice.

Comment: @MyMolecules Yes something that is as immediate and useful as a determinant if it exists.

Comment: What is a (the) "straight lines bisector"? Why don't you like the formula (1) ?

Comment: If you mean a segment length use $AB$ or $|AB|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be similar enough to what you're looking for.

Represent the points as vectors $A=(x_a,y_a)$, $B=(x_b,y_b)$, $C=(x_c,y_c)$. Let a point $(p:q:r)$ stand for
$$\frac{pA+qB+rC}{p+q+r},$$
so that $A=(1:0:0)$, $B=(0:1:0)$, $C=(0:0:1)$; we want to show that the incenter is $(a:b:c)$. (These are called *barycentric coordinates*, and the ``extra dimension,'' using three coordinates instead of just two, comes from the fact that if you scale $p$, $q$, and $r$ each by the same amount, the point it represents doesn't change.)

It shouldn't be too hard to convince yourself that lines can, in this system, be represented by a triple $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$, and consist of the points $(p:q:r)$ with $\alpha p+\beta q+\gamma r=0$. You can see this by considering the places in which a line intersects each of the sides of the triangle.

Now, let's find the equation of the bisector of $\angle BAC$. We know this line contains $A$, and it also contains the point $D$ on $BC$ with $\frac{BD}{DC}=\frac cb$. This point can be represented as $(0:b:c)$. So, the bisector of $\angle BAC$ is the line $0p+cq-br=0$, or equivalently $\frac qb=\frac rc$.

By symmetry, the three angle bisectors intersect at the point $(p:q:r)$ with $\frac pa=\frac qb=\frac rc$, i.e. the point $(a:b:c)$.

A side-note: You mention looking for a way to show this using determinants. While this isn't as direct, one can show that area in barycentric coordinates is closely related to determinants, in that if you have three points $(p_1:q_1:r_1)$, $(p_2:q_2:r_2)$, and $(p_3:q_3:r_3)$, *normalized* such that
$$p+1+q_1+r_1=p_2+q_2+r_2=p_3+q_3+r_3=1,$$
then the area of the triangle represented by these three points is
$$\begin{vmatrix}p_1&q_1&r_1\\p_2&q_2&r_2\\p_3&q_3&r_3\end{vmatrix}$$
times the area of $ABC$. One way to define the incenter is as the unique point $I$ inside $ABC$ for which
$$\frac{\operatorname{Area}(IBC)}a=\frac{\operatorname{Area}(ICA)}b=\frac{\operatorname{Area}(IAB)}c.$$
Applying this barycentric area formula gives you the same result as before, i.e. that $I=(a:b:c)$. I believe this proof can, with enough work, be translated out of barycentric coordinates and into Cartesian, using the determinant version of the shoelace formula.

Comment: Thank you very very very very much.